# scrapy javascript pagination href=#

Tags: javascript, pagination, scrapy

I'm using scrapy & splash to crawl promotion deals from a javascript enabled bank page.

https://www.dbs.com.sg/personal/product-promotion-list.page?pct=Cards#

The problem i'm facing is the pagination within it is done using javascript hence the links are in this format:

```
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
```

The href links are all hidden within the #.

As i dig further, the pagination function within the html code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    productList();
    });
    $('.pagination').on("click","a",checkClass);
    $('#filterSearch').on("click",searchTextChange);
    $('form').submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#Search").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#filterSearch").click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Can anyone help me with this ? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking on each paging (1, 2 or 3), the following URL is requested from the server using POST:

```
https://www.dbs.com.sg/personal/product-promotion-list-child.page
```

with the following posted form data:

`promotype=&start=1&pageNum=1&search=&type=promotion&pct=Cards` (page 1)
`promotype=&start=2&pageNum=1&search=&type=promotion&pct=Cards` (page 2)
`promotype=&start=3&pageNum=1&search=&type=promotion&pct=Cards` (page 3)

What if you hit this URL directly passing the correct page number? This request returns HTML with the list of promotions that you want.

Comment: Thanks , that solve the problem. Can I ask how do you find out about this? Is it by inspecting the network ?

Comment: Yes, using Chrome, press F12 and go to the "Network" tab. Every call to the server is logged there... Set the answer as correct if it has helped you. Cheers!